# Converting a textbox into any other html element

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form name="txt" method="post">

<input type="text" name="select" id="select" onclick="return selectbox();">
</form>
```

Now through js or html can I change my textbox into a select or a list box. Is it possible by any way.

//js code

```
function selectbox()
{
var select=document.getElementById('select');
select.innerHTML="<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>";
}
```

Something like this should happen. In the place of the textbox the below code should appear
//new textbox

```
<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
```

Comment: Your question is too vague, you want to convert it to a `select`? What do you want to convert? And how? Should every new line indicate an option, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for example:

```
var select = document.createElement("select");
select.innerHTML = "<option value='1'>One</option>" +
                   "<option value='2'>Two</option>" +
                   "<option value='3'>Three</option>";
select.id = "select";
select.name = "select";
select.onclick = function(){return selectbox()};
var currentSelect = document.getElementById("select");
currentSelect.parentNode.replaceChild(select, currentSelect);
select.focus(); //Focus on the element
```

This code snippet creates a `<select>` element, and adds new options to it through `.innerHTML`. Then, the attributes are set. Finally. the script selects the current element with `id="select"` from the HTML document, and replaces the element by the newly created element.

Answer (score 2):

Be more specific about what and how. You can try following

```
function selectbox(Sender){         
    var select = document.createElement('select');
    //UPDATE
    for(var i=1; i<=2; i++)
       select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i, i);
    Sender.parentNode.appendChild(select);
    Sender.parentNode.removeChild(Sender);
}
```